# Is the syntax of Oracle 10g and MySQL the same?

Tags: mysql, oracle-10g

Is the syntax of Oracle10g and mysql are the same? For example the select query? Thanks, I'm using MySQL and want to try Oracle 10g for my java.

Comment: There are way too many differences. But don't use Oracle 10g, it's out of support since a few years, go for 12c (or maybe 11gR2)

Comment: From your link "However MySQL silently ignores the `CHECK` constraint" is enough. No `CTE`s or windowing (analytic) functions.... I could go on. MySQL is a lucky toy. PostgreSQL is a real industrial standard RDBMS. You are correct though - it's up to DBA/devs to choose.

Comment: Maybe 70% of the lines of SQL will be 'compatible'.  Expecting portability of SQL is folly.

Answer (score 1):

They're vastly different when it comes to other features, such as security, programming languages, data types, tools, end user support, requirements, etc.

However, they're both compliant with basic SQL92 (and perhaps other SQL standards), so one can do the same basic schema creation and data querying and manipulation. You should be able to do the basics from java applications without noticing where you're connected to (and this applies to several other databases).

Comment: In limiting yourself to the standard, you must forgo various extensions, some of which are significant performance improvements.